# How to bring dynamicaly scope in view

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have this code:

```
$scope.lists = [{
  listName: 'list1'
}, {
  listName: 'list2'
}];

angular.forEach($scope.lists, function(item) {
  var listName = item.listName;
  $scope[listName] = [{
    Name: 'Stefan'
  }, {
    Name: 'Stefan'
  }, {
    Name: 'Stefan'
  }, {
    Name: 'Stefan'
  }];
});
```

The Input from lists cames from a webservice, so the values (list1 and list2) can be different each time i reload the app. I can also more then 2 items in lists.
How can I show the value from `$scope[listName]` in an `ng-repat` section in my view?

Thanks for your Help.
Stefan.

Comment: are you want to show `list1` or `list2` in the view ?

Comment: I changed the code. Now I want to show "Stefan" in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", []).controller("controller", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.lists = [{
        listName: "list1"
      }, {
        listName: "list2"
      }];

      angular.forEach($scope.lists, function(item) {
        var listName = item.listName;
        $scope[listName] = [{
          Name: "Stefan"
        }, {
          Name: "Stefan"
        }, {
          Name: "Stefan"
        }, {
          Name: "Stefan"
        }];
        $scope.results = $scope[listName];
      });
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in results">{{item.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```